# (Jacobson Basic Algebra I: 0.2.2)Show that $\alpha:S \to T$ is injective if and only if there exists a $\beta:T \to S$ such that $\beta\alpha=1_s$

Tags: functions

The question is pretty straightforward if $\alpha$ is surjective. However, I am confused what to do if we assume $\alpha$ is not surjective. Is it okay to let $\beta$ be arbitrary whenever there is $t$ such that $\alpha(s) \neq t$ for all $s$? In other words, choose $\beta(t) = s$ if there exists an $s$ such that $a(s) = t$, and then $\beta(t) = \alpha(x)$ for some $x \in S$ if there does not exist an image of $t$ under $\alpha$.

Comment: What is $T$? The target of $\alpha$ is $B$

Comment: I think I made an error, $\alpha: S \to T$.

Comment: Yes, it's okay. But only if $S\neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false if $S=\varnothing$ and $T\neq\varnothing$; in that case, every function $\alpha\colon S\to T$ is injective (by vacuity), but there are no functions $T\to S$ at all.

But if we assume that both $S$ and $T$ are nonempty, then the result holds.

If $\beta$ exists, then $\beta\circ \alpha$ is one-to-one, hence the first function in the composition, $\alpha$, is one-to-one.

Conversely, assume that $\alpha$ is one-to-one. Let $s_0\in S$ be arbitrary (this is where we use $S\neq\varnothing$). Define $\beta\colon T\to S$ as follows:
$$\beta(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
s_0&\text{if }t\notin \alpha(S),\\
s&\text{if }\alpha(s)=t.
\end{array}\right.$$
I leave it to you to show that this is well-defined (there is no ambiguity in the definition because $s$ exists and is unique), and that $\beta\alpha=1_S$.

When $\alpha$ is also surjective, this map is uniquely determined (it is the inverse of $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is injective but not surjective, then in general it has many left inverses (unless $S$ is a singleton).